# Area under the convolution proof

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification

Prove that $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty (f*g)(x)dx=\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx\right)\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)dx\right)$

My proof is:

Let $f$ and $g$ be probability density functions and let $x,t\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty(f*g)(x)\,dx=$

$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)g(x-t)\,dt\,dx =  \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)g(x-t)\,dx\,dt = $

$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \left( \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty g(x-t)\,dx \right) \,dt \overset{?}{=}  \left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \,dt\right)  \left( \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\,dx \right)$.

Thus $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty (f*g)(x)dx=\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)dx\right)\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)dx\right)$ since $t,x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Is this a correct proof and if so I am having trouble mentally justifying the equality with the ? though I know it must be true

Comment: You can write it as: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\left[\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x-t)dx}_{\mbox{this is a constant $c$}}\right]dt = c\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)dt $$ Does that help?

Comment: So, your proof is correct but you can fill in a missing detail if you like.  Can you prove that the above expression (marked by the underbrace) is indeed a constant $c$ (independent of $t$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fixed $t$, $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x-t)\mathrm{d}x,$$ as can be verified with a variable substitution for $x-t$. This integral is a constant, so you are indeed justified in this step.